# Wordpress and custom Coading

Tags: wordpress

Please Help me i want  only on one page get post from category
here is my code but it is not working.

```
$thepost =  new WP_Query( 'cat_id=3&page_id=69' ); 
    while ($thepost -> have_posts()) : $thepost -> the_post(); 
    the_content(); 
     endwhile;`
```

Comment: is there any result? show it. Is there an error message? show it. edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test it now - but you can try this:

```
if(is_page(69)){
  $thepost = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => 3 ) ); 
  while ($thepost -> have_posts()) : $thepost -> the_post(); 
    the_content(); 
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Please take a look into the wordpress codex for WP_Query.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

Comment: Don't forget to reset the $post gobal `wp_reset_postdata();`.